# Configure Permissions in Mamp

Tags: permissions

I recently built a website on Mamp, and upon uploading to my hosting server, I seem to have lost permissions.  My guess is that the migration from local to server brought the permissions with it.

You can see here `http://162.213.156.137/~healthy/`, in the left lower area of footer that the images are not loading in.  I also had the two images in the header (little girl and logo) not load in either until I used FTP to manually change permissions.

I'm wondering if anyone has dealt this before and has advice or if you know how to configure MAMP to have proper settings from the get go.

Answer (score 1):

Your local site is on a Mac, which uses a different users and groups system than a production (linux) environment. I would recommend that you change the permissions to what they should be on the local dev environment to what they should be before you upload them to a production/QA environment.

Please refer to [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) for more on the specific permission recommendations on WordPress.